# folder level authentication fails while using .htaccess encryption

Tags: mysql, apache, .htaccess, encryption

I am trying to authenticate a user in folder level using .htaccess file.

And my .htaccess file has the following lines for password encryption. It basically uses SHA1Sum as the encryption type.

```
AuthMySQL_Password_Field passwd
AuthMySQL_Empty_Passwords off
AuthMySQL_Encryption_Types SHA1Sum
```

Now. I have updated some of my passwords using the following query.

```sql
update `auth_users` set passwd=SHA1(1234) WHERE user_id = 1
```

I use SHA1(1234), because I think that is the correct encryption function for SHA1Sum type.

A 40 character encrypted password is updated in the table. Now when go for the respective page it pops up the dialogbox to enter username and password.

For some reason even when I pass the correct password its not letting me in. What could be the reason behind this. Am I doing anything incorrectly. please give your thoughts

Comment: what does the rest of the .htaccess file look like?

Comment: Your question appears to relate to Apache so I've tagged it as such. If this is not the case, please remove my tag and add the correct tag for your web server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have found a guide for an outdated Apache 1.x version of `mod_auth_mysql`.  Try checking out this guide from [the modauthmysql guys](http://modauthmysql.sourceforge.net/CONFIGURE)

your htaccess options should look like (you won't need all of them, this is just to document what the options look like.  Note the lack of underscores)

```
AuthMySQLEnable On
AuthMySQLHost localhost
AuthMySQLPort <default port in MySQL>
AuthMySQLSocket <default socket in MySQL>
AuthMySQLUser <no default -- NULL>
AuthMySQLPassword <no default -- NULL>
AuthMySQLDB test
AuthMySQLUserTable user_info
AuthMySQLUserCondition <no default>
AuthMySQLNameField user_name
AuthMySQLPasswordField user_passwd
AuthMySQLNoPasswd Off
AuthMySQLPwEncryption sha1
AuthMySQLSaltField <>
AuthMySQLGroupTable <defaults to value of AuthMySQLUserTable>
AuthMySQLGroupCondition <no default>
AuthMySQLGroupField <no default>
AuthMySQLKeepAlive Off
AuthMySQLAuthoritative On
AuthMySQLCharacterSet <no default>
```

Comment: Thank u for your inputs. Actually the issue was solved when our SA installed some missing modules in our new server. Thank you